# Use a string with forward slashes as a single parameter in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Sorry about that confusing title :)  I have a resource, ComatosePage (used in the comatose cms plugin), which has a table called comatose_pages which has a field 'full_path' which has values like this: `"en/home/logged-in/subscriber/school-top"` to set up a route so that i can use this full_path field to load a ComatosePage from the db, instead of the standard id field, so that this url:

```
/comatose_admin/en/home/logged-in/subscriber/school-top
```

loads the comatose_admin controller's edit action, passing everything after comatose_admin/ through as a parameter, ie generates this for rails:

```
Parameters: {:controller => "comatose_admin", :action => "edit", :full_path => "en/home/logged-in/subscriber/school-top"}
```

The complication lies in the fact that the string is broken up with forward slashes, which is going to confuse routes, i think.  Can i set up routes to take everything after "comatose_admin/" and put it into a single parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use wildcards in your routes that will match forward slashes. Try something like this:

```
"/comatose_admin/*full_path"
```

Then `params[:full_path]` should contain the rest of the request path.

See [Route Globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing)

Comment: That sounds perfect Ben but doesn't work for me, i get a 'no route matches...' error :(  I'm in rails 2.3.4, is this a feature of a later version of rails?  Also, I'm familiar with regexes generally but i don't understand yours, ie i don't understand what it's telling routes.  I tried this as well `"/comatose_admin/:full_path{.*}"` but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Max Williams, my mistake, that was from an actually *older* version of rails, not a newer one. I just updated it -- the updated for should work for you (and is also much easier to understand -- it just uses a glob, no regular expression).

Comment: @Max, I also just added a link to the rails docs about "Route Globbing" where this syntax is explained a little further.

Comment: Thanks a lot ben - that works!  it actually splits the rest of the url into an array of strings, one per section, but that's fine for my purposes: `"full_path"=>["en", "home", "logged-in", "subscriber", "school-top"]`.  Thanks for the link too, 'route globbing' is the sort of thing that's hard to google as i'd never think to search for 'route globbing' :) Cheers! max